# State Space Observer Control

Tags: control-systems

I am attempting to implement observer based state feedback in C and can't figure it out.

Here is pseudocode of the algorithm:

```
//Initialize Stuff

loop:

//read process variable                                                                                 
y = read(ch1)  

//compute control variable                                                                      
u = -K * xhat 

//set process input                                                                             
write(u) 

//update state estimate                                                                                  
xhat = xhat + Ts * (A*xhat + B*u + L*(y-C*xhat))

// repeat loop
```

- xhat is the estimated state
- K is the feedback gain
- L is the observer gain
- y is the system output
- u is the system input
- Ts is the sampling period
- A, B, & C are the state space matrices

Is this how observer feedback is supposed to be implemented?

Here is the actual code I have for the loop:

```
// Get Process Output from Sensors:
y[0] = sensor1();
y[1] = sensor2();

// Compute Control Variable:
u = 0;  
for (i=0; i<4; i++)         
    u += K[i]*xhat[i];

// Set Process Input:
write_to_DAC(u);

// Calculate: A*xhat + B*u
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    Ax_Bu[i] = 0;
    for (j=0; j<4; j++)
        Ax_Bu[i] += A[i*4+j]*xhat[j];    
    Ax_Bu[i] += B[i]*u; 
}

// Calculate: y-y_hat
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    yhat[i]   = 0;
    y_yhat[i] = 0;  
    for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
        yhat[i] +=  C[i*4+j]*xhat[j]; // Calculate yhat = C*xhat
        y_yhat[i] = y[i]-yhat[i];     // Calculate the 'Innovation'
    }             
}

// Calculate: L*(y-y_hat)
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    L_y_yhat[i] = 0;
    for (j=0; j<2; j++) 
        L_y_yhat[i] += L[i*2+j]*y_yhat[j];    
}   

// Update State Estimate:
for (i=0; i<4; i++) 
    xhat[i] += Ts*(Ax_Bu[i] + L_y_yhat[i]);
```

Comment: What is there to figure out? What can't you figure out? [Does looking at some matlab code help in your understanding?](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/~wedeward/EE544/FA05/example8.html)

Comment: I am confused in the implementation.  With the pseudo code I wrote the system input u seems to just keep increasing in every iteration of the loop.  So my question is if what I have written is a correct implementation.

Comment: Well, since you haven't shown the equations for $K$ and $L$, you can't really say `u seems to just keep increasing`.  It's a feedback system: and $K$, $L$, $xhat$ are vectors, not scalars (unless it's a very simple system).

Comment: $ u $ is a scalar, and all others are vectors/matrices: $ K $ is 4x1, $ L $ is 4x2, $ A $ is 4x4, $ B $ is 4x1, $ C $ is 2x4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $y$ and $u$ are scalars, then the first equation:

$$
u = -K \hat{x}
$$

is just a vector-vector multiplication and can be implemented in `C` as:

```
u = 0.0;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{  
    u += xhat[i]*K[i];
}
```

assuming that $K$ is $1 \times N$ and that $\hat{x}$ is $N \times 1$.

The multiplication `C*xhat` can be implemented similarly (because I suspect that $C$ is really $1 \times N$ rather than $2 \times N$).

The multiplications `L*(y-C*xhat)` and `B*u` are vector-scalar multiplications which, for the latter, would look like:

```
Bu = 0.0;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{  
    Bu += B[i]*u;
}
```

The multiplication  `A*xhat`  will be slightly different because $A$ is $N \times N$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Peter.  $C$ is 2x4.  And does the order of the loop in my original post look correct?

Comment: OK, that means $y$ must be $2 \times 1$; I assumed it was  scalar. No real matter.

Regarding the loop order: I would have thought the LAST thing to do would be `write(u)`... but it depends on the indices in the original equations.

Comment: In the line where the state estimate is updated is it proper to multiply that term by the sampling period?  I am referring to: Ts * (A*xhat + B*u + L*(y-C*xhat))

Comment: That Ts term often shows up. You'd have to point me to the origin of the equations before I could say unequivocally.

Comment: I got the algorithm from pages 136-137 on this document: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa04/caltech/am04_ch5-24oct04.pdf

Comment: I edited the original post to include the actual code of the algorithm. It does not seem to work. Is the code correct?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried everything I can think of.  All of the estimated states just continually grow.  Does anyone see anything wrong with that code?

Comment: Can you provide some numerical examples? How are you calculating `K[i]` and `L[i]` ?

Comment: I am designing $K$ and $L$ as described on this page (the project is an inverted pendulum on a cart): http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=InvertedPendulum&section=ControlStateSpace